# How does vscode support automatic json validation using https://schemastore.org/json/?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Should VSCode have automatic intellisense in JSON files? If so, how does it work? I know it works for well-known JSON files, like tsconfig.json, but what about other resources like stryker.conf.json?

In a number of resources online I read that it should automagically work for any schema in https://schemastore.org/json, for example: https://joshuaavalon.io/intellisense-json-yaml-vs-code. However, it doesn't seem to work for stryker.conf.json, however, it is in the schema store.

[image]

https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/e4920405e29addb278cc68dd14831700d038f937/src/api/json/catalog.json#L1081-L1086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode will give intellisense for JSON whenever it has a valid schema to use, hosted at schemastore.org or anywhere else.  It just needs to know what schema to use for which files.

As you noted, VSCode just "knows" what schema to use for certain well-known files, like `tsconfig.json`.

For other files, you can specify the schema directly in the JSON, which is what VSCode is prompting you to do in your screenshot:

[image: Intellisense with schema specified in file]

If you don't want to specify the schema in the JSON file itself, you can map file patterns to schemas in `settings.json`:

```
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["stryker.conf.json"],
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stryker-mutator/stryker/master/packages/api/schema/stryker-core.json"
    }
  ]
```

[image: Intellisense without schema specified in file]

Comment: You say: "It just needs to know what schema to use for which files". This is something schemastore also provides with "fileMatch": https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/api/json/catalog.json

But fileMatch is not used?

If so, is there a hardcoded list of supported files with schema locations somewhere? I would love to add stryker.conf.json to this list.

Comment: This may or may not be the [hard-coded list](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/99d63cc02b5e1ac753261f32f977a95255d0e057/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json#L54) you're looking for.  Good luck!  Disclaimer: I am NOT a VSCode developer.

Comment: Thanks. If you add that to the answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Too bad vscode does no dynamic resolving :/